# How can I manually set the channel delays on my Asus Xonar D2 sound card?

Tags: audio, 5.1

I'm using a Xonar D2 with a piece of test equipment that's very sensitive to the timing of a 5.1 audio signal.  Unfortunately, the sound card is adding a delay to some of the channels (15ms for the surround speakers, 5ms for the center speaker), throwing off the calculations in my test equipment.  The driver settings app offers only very basic controls to do this, and may even remix the sound, which would be a Bad Thing (TM).

I could adjust for the delays in the audio files that I'm using, but I don't want to do that because it would make them incompatible with other 5.1 sound equipment.  Fixing the problem at the sound card level is the preferred approach.

Comment: Couldn't you adjust for the delays in COPIES of the audio files you're using?  Since you already know the exact delays, this seems easiest.

Comment: Yes, making copies and adjusting the channels in the copies is possible and relatively straight forward.  However, adjusting each file by hand (which could end up numbering in the hundreds) would be time consuming, and adding to the code that generates my sound files just to deal with this one sound card is impractical, since my existing files would need to be regenerated.

Comment: I underestimated the scale and complexity of these files; I see what you mean. (I certainly didn't think they were GENERATED - what on earth are they for anyway?) I will say I've used similar Xonar cards before and am not aware of any way to do what you want. :/

Comment: @Shinrai: This is for work, so I can't say much more.  [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/293591/make-an-m-audio-profire-610-show-up-as-a-5-1-device) uses the same external test equipment and files, but deals with a different sound card and different problem.